# iOS continuous photo App

Tags: ios, applications, software-recommendation, photos, ios-appstore

I'm searching for an app (for my iPhone 5S) that takes photos (without stopping) every X seconds. The requirement is an app that takes photos, not videos or directly generates a time lapse animation.

For example: I set "shoot every 1.00 second" and here it is: the phone starts taking pictures every second (through that app of course).

Does anyone know some app for that no matter if it's free or paid?

Answer (score 1):

Suggested cool apps:

- Hyperlapse (you can set the fastness, which is not possible with iPhone time-lapse)
- Osnap, which does cost 3.99 but it's worth it!